# Mobile Safari - Javascript open tab without losing focus on current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile-safari

I'm currently working on a webpage that, when visited, opens up two more webpages in mobile safari.

The only issue is that when the new tabs are loaded, the browser is focusing on the final one to load.

I've tried setting the Safari setting 'Open Links -> In Background' but this only seems to give you the option of holding down on a link then manually selecting to open the link in background (thus remaining focused on the current page).

Is there anyway to automatically open a weblink in Mobile Safari using javascript without losing focus on the current webpage?

Here is an example of the code I am currently using.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a class="site" href="bbcNews/www.bbc.co.uk/news/index.html" target="_blank">Open Tabs</a>
    <script>
        $('a').each(function () {
            var clk = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            clk.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, true, 0, null);
            this.dispatchEvent(clk);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not going to be able to do what you want here. I think it's primarily because you are using Javascript to open the other tabs, so the browser isn't really seeing them as "links", per-se. There's nothing at all you can do on the website code to fix that, in any case. Not if you really need two pages opened.

Comment: Yes that was the conclusion i came to in the end. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

I am using a for a long time this kind of logic for "pop-unders".
Hope this will be useful for you:
-Basic idea is to open page itself in new tab and, in the same time, redirect "old" tab/page to some other location

```
  function popunder_redirect(){
      window.open("#tab");
      window.location="http://redirecturl.com";
    }
```

Now, as you can see, you have hash link (#tab) right next to your original page link that you can use as some kind of fake history to adjust your javascript or some other page progress thru checking on page load:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){



var hashValue = window.location.hash;     //get hash value

//check for hash value

if (hashValue!=undefined && hashValue=="#tab")

{
      //display progressed page}

else{
     //display start page
}

});
```